# Cannot boot from USB - HP Envy

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, 13.10

I'm having a little bit of a problem right now...  I am trying to install Ubuntu, whether it be the 12.04LTS or 13.10, but I can't seem to get my PC to even run into my bootable USB.

I am trying to at least boot into Ubuntu off the USB so I can see if the Network Card will work and be able to grab wifi.  When I open my boot source when I start my PC, I can click on the USB drive, but it will tell me that it cannot authenticate it(paraphrasing loosely of course).  I'm using an **HP ENVY TS m6 Sleekbook** with Windows 8 (64-bit).

I would definitely appreciate someone's help, so if Ubuntu is compatible with my network card, I can learn more about Ubuntu and such.  Thank you in advance.

Specs:

- OS: Windows 8 64-bit
- CPU: AMD A10 @ 2.10GHz
- RAM: 6GB
- Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 8610G
- HDD: 698GB Seagate (SATA)

Comment: Try disabling [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) boot. It sounds like [it is enabled and blocking your attempt to boot & install.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) [How to Boot and Install Linux on a UEFI PC With Secure Boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/)

Comment: I have tried these for Ubuntu 13.10 on my USB and it hasn't seemed to work.  Does 13.10 support SecureBoot and such?  Or should I try these steps with the LTS?  If I do that and that doesn't work, should I try the 'Legacy Boot Support'?  I'm not sure what most of this is due to a new PC, OS, and BIOS which all I've never been introduced to before.  Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I think I have secure boot enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu won't boot from a USB on my Windows 8 laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/257479/ubuntu-wont-boot-from-a-usb-on-my-windows-8-laptop)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some time ago with 12.04.
 I disabled the secure boot(by going into the BIOS usually F2 during boot)

I was unable to boot from the USB drive,  I then tried changing the priority in the BIOS (USB first). This worked for me in the past, (after disabling the secure boot of course) and booted from the USB with no issues, after installing 12.04 I then returned the HD to 1st in the boot priority.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on your computer with win 8 and mount usb device. Then double click wubi.exe. It is the helper to run ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

2022, I still faced issue making HP Envy x360 recognize bootable ubuntu 22.04. Create bootable usb using Startup Disk Creator won't work for me.

Since this thread still come up in search results, I document how did I resolved it here https://chanon.info/install-ubuntu-22.04-on-hp-envy-x360/ in case it help those who come across this in 2022 too.

Answer (score -1):

I was having a problem booting from a USB drive. I tried everything and nothing seemed to work well. I ended up using a newer USB drive and it worked. Sometimes certain USB drives don't work well with certain laptops. In my case it was a Lexar 16 GB thumb drive and my Yoga 2 Pro. Once I used my brother's San Disk, it worked like a charm. If all else fails, don't forget this! Good luck!

Comment: This doea not answer the question also you can find a list of bootable usbs on the wiki boot from usb page.