# How to boot from an Ubuntu USB?

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu

My laptop is running windows 10, build 9926. I would like to install Ubuntu or Kubuntu over windows 10. I have USB drives formatted and ready with the ISO files of Ubuntu and Kubuntu. (each drive has one ISO). For some reason, my laptop doesn't recognize an available USB to boot the computer from. I don't have a CD to boot from either. I am at a loss, is there a way that I can install Ubuntu without using a CD or a USB?

Comment: How about this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257479/ubuntu-wont-boot-from-a-usb-on-my-windows-8-laptop?rq=1 It also looks like installing is the next step you've not gotten to yet, and the problem at hand is booting from an Ubuntu USB. I think the new title reflects it better.

Comment: @WyattFerguson If you use LiLi (linux live usb installer) It will make the flash drive both BIOS and UEFI compatible. Hopefully your bios is only one or the other, and that's why it didn't show before.

Answer (score 0):

May be your BIOS do not support booting from USB in which case nobody can help you. You will have to use a VD/DVD. Another possible way that uses Unetbootin is described in this post: [Install Ubuntu without CD and USB , how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how) Check it out.

Answer (score -2):

You can't install it with just the ISO file. Use `Unetbootin` (downloadable tool, not command) to install Ubuntu on the USB, then reboot into said USB. Select the option to install Ubuntu.

At this point, install it normally like you would for a dual boot by allocating some of your disk space to the Ubuntu partition. Pay attention to the amounts; you'll use them later. Then boot into the live USB again and select "Try Ubuntu" to boot into a live session.

Now that you are in the live session, open the application `GParted`. It is a partition manager. From this partition manager, you will see several partitions. You can tell which they are by the amounts of disk space they take up. Identify the one that has your Windows system on it (usually `/dev/sda1`), unlock it (if necessary), and delete/format it. It should now be labeled as empty space. Then, unlock your Ubuntu partition and resize it so it fills your whole disk. Then wait for GParted to finish working, relock your partition, and reboot into your regular system.

You should now have only Ubuntu installed, with your whole disk available to it.

Comment: The OP clearly said "For some reason, my laptop doesn't recognize an available USB to boot the computer from", so your suggestion will not work for him

Comment: @Ron You can't boot from a USB with just the ISO on it; it has to be specially formatted, which can be done with Unetbootin. The USB isn't recognized because it's not bootable.

Comment: I thought that i formatted it correctly, when i use it on my desktop, it boots directly into ubuntu, from there allowing me to install it or not.

Comment: @WyattFerguson What do you mean by "when you use it on your desktop"?

Comment: I have 2 computers, I'm trying to install it on my laptop, but the USB only works on my desktop computer.

Comment: @WyattFerguson Is this when you boot your desktop from the USB or something else?

Comment: Yes, when i boot my desktop from the usb it goes into ubuntu.

Comment: @WyattFerguson Did you use Unetbootin to make the USB or just put the ISO on it?

Comment: I used a program called universal usb installer from pendrivelinux.com

Comment: @WyattFerguson The one that worked for me was Unetbootin. I recommend going on your laptop computer and installing Ubuntu onto the USB using Unetbootin from there, and then trying again. If that doesn't work then I don't know what to do, I'm sorry.

Comment: @WyattFerguson Did it work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, my laptop did not recognize the USB as a bootable drive.

Comment: @WyattFerguson I'm not sure what to do then, sorry. Try posting a bounty or Googling. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @WyattFerguson If you use LiLi (linux live usb installer) It will make the flash drive both BIOS and UEFI compatible. Hopefully your bios is only one or the other, and that's why it didn't show before.